# With ctx.setTansform, fabric js object selection not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricJS to draw different shapes over a fabric canvas. My canvas as an image object and that is scaled. Now when I draw a star without using this `ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);` means comment this ctx.setTransform then Fabric Star object is selectable but when I use this `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` then fabric star object is not selectable.

I have tried this `canvas.setViewportTransform([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);` to transform but in this case my stars are not drawing at required place means due to scaling they draw at different X,Y points.

```
function drawStars(data){
     drawStar(data.x,data.y,data.spikes,5,1,data.color);
}

function drawStar(cx, cy, spikes, radius, isRGB, statusColor) {
var innerRadius = radius;
var outerRadius = radius / 2;
var rot = Math.PI / 2 * 3;
var x = cx;
var y = cy;
var step = Math.PI / spikes;

var starPoints = [];

starPoints.push({ x: cx, y: cy - outerRadius });
for (i = 0; i < spikes; i++) {
    x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * outerRadius;
    y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * outerRadius;
    starPoints.push({ x: x, y: y });
    rot += step;

    x = cx + Math.cos(rot) * innerRadius;
    y = cy + Math.sin(rot) * innerRadius;
    starPoints.push({ x: x, y: y });
    rot += step;
}
starPoints.push({ x: cx, y: cy - outerRadius });

var starPolygon = new fabric.Polygon(starPoints, {
    fill: (isRGB) ? statusColor : "#" + statusColor,
    selectable: true,
    name: "Polygon",
    type: 'normal'
});
canvas.add(starPolygon);
canvas.renderAll();
//canvas.setActiveObject(starPolygon);
canvas.bringForward(starPolygon);
canvas.bringToFront(starPolygon);
```

}

```
scaleAndPositionImage = function () {
canvas.clear();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
//ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
//canvas.setViewportTransform([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);

var objects = canvas.getObjects();
for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].setCoords();
}

//setCanvasZoom();

if (bgImage.width === 0) bgImage.width = canvasWidth;
if (bgImage.height === 0) bgImage.height = canvasHeight;

var canvasAspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;
var imgAspect = bgImage.width / bgImage.height;


if (canvasAspect >= imgAspect) {
    scaleFactor = canvasWidth / bgImage.width;
    canvasLeft = 0;
    canvasTop = -((bgImage.height * scaleFactor) - canvasHeight) / 2;

} else {
    scaleFactor = canvasHeight / bgImage.height;
    canvasTop = 0;
    canvasLeft = -((bgImage.width * scaleFactor) - canvasWidth) / 2;

}
if (scaleFactor === Infinity) { scaleFactor = 1; }
canvasTop = 0;
canvasLeft = 0;
//console.log("Top: " + canvasTop, "Left: " + canvasLeft, "ScaleFactor: " + scaleFactor, "img Width: " + bgImage.width, "canvas Width: " + canvasWidth);

bgImage.set({
    "name": "image",
    "left": canvasLeft,
    "top": canvasTop,
    "scaleX": canvas.width / bgImage.width,
    "scaleY": canvas.height / bgImage.height,
    "selectable": false,
    hoverCursor: "move"
});
//console.log(canvas);
canvas.add(bgImage);


canvas.renderAll();
drawStar(lotsData);
}
```

Please help.